# In-app FB Page plugin link in browser window

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, jsx

I'm using Facebook page plugin in an hybrid app developed using worklight (6.2.01) like this:

```
<div id="facebook-toc-feed" className="toc-feed">
    <iframe id="fb-feed" src={"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F" + constants.FB_TOC_FEEDS_URL + "&width="+ this.wWidth +"&height=" + this.wHeight + "&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&header=false&stream=true&show_border=false&appId=" + constants.FB_APP_ID}></iframe>
</div>
```

Implementation is being done with JSX
I wonder if it is possible to make links on FB plugin to be opened in browser instead of the app itself?
Now when I click any link in plugin (post link, page name) it opens it inside the app itself and its impossible to navigate back to the app.

P.S. Not sure if this will be helpful, but strangely only iframe displays the plugin. The iframe itself is in radio type tab:

```
<div className="social-wrapper full-content">
    <div className="content-tabs no-shadow">
        <input
            type="radio"
            id="social-radio-facebook"
            name="social-radio"
            value="facebook"
            defaultChecked="true"
        ></input>
        <label htmlFor="social-radio-facebook" onClick={this.showFB}>
            <div className="social-icon facebook">
                <div>{Messages.facebook}</div>
            </div>
        </label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            id="social-radio-twitter"
            name="social-radio"
            value="twitter"
        />
        <label htmlFor="social-radio-twitter" onClick={this.showTwitter}>
            <div className="social-icon twitter">
                <div>{Messages.twitter}</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="facebook-toc-feed" className="toc-feed">
        <iframe
            id="fb-feed"
            src={
                "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F" +
                constants.FB_TOC_FEEDS_URL +
                "&width=" +
                this.wWidth +
                "&height=" +
                this.wHeight +
                "&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&header=false&stream=true&show_border=false&appId=" +
                constants.FB_APP_ID
            }
        ></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="twitter-toc-feed" className="toc-feed">
        <div
            id="twitter-toc-feed-widget"
            className="twitter-timeline"
            data-chrome="nofooter transparent"
            data-widget-id={constants.TWITTER_WIDGET_ID}
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

So if plugin should be implemented in other tag than iframe please take note of above.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the Cordova InAppBrowser plug-in to open a browser window, or even the external browser itself.

`var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank');`